# Authorization not working with Post, Put or Patch in Azure App Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC / Web API app I am deploying to Azure which uses the ASP.NET Authentication Framework. It uses cookie authentication with VueJs on the front end.

When I deploy to Azure Web Services, the `[Authorize]` attribute returns a 401 for all Patch, Put or Post calls. However, for all Get calls, the `[Authorize]` attribute works fine, and the API call is authenticated.

I've tried removing the `[Authorize]` attribute and inspected the claims and identity. Again, for all non Get calls, the identity is empty and `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false.

But if I just change it back to a Get call, then all identity information comes through.

I can't think of any reason why the .NET authentication stack would great a Get call differently than a Post call when deployed on Azure.

Locally on my dev machine, and on a regular IIS deployment everything works fine. I've inspected the http packets, and the identity cookie is being sent by the client.

Any pointers on where to look is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds very strange, could you use the fiddler to capture the http request ?

Comment: And could you create a sample project for us to reproduce the issue ? Pls hide the sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the scenario when using postman to create the users Which uses POST request.

GET  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

[image]

Even for GET , i was getting unauthorized as previously read permissions are not given and invalid bearer tpoken was given

[image]

- You must be missing receiving auth access token , please add the authorization header in the code which is done In the **Configure method** in `Startup.cs` class

  ```
  app.UseSession();
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
     {
         var JWToken = context.Session.GetString("Token");
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Token))
         {
             context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token);
         }
         await next();
     });
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseAuthorization();
  ```
- check the scope is provided in controller part where [Authorize] attribute is given.
- Check [Protect a web API with the Microsoft identity platform - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-api-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet-core)

I could get the GET request response successfully after giving below permissions

[image]

I have these Directory.Read.All and User.Read delegated and application permissions only.

[image]

POST request needs write permissions , in my case to create users , it requires `User.ReadWrite.All` and `Directory.ReadWrite.All` Application permissions

[Create User - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

***After giving required permissions and getting admin grant consent .***

[image]

***I could  execute the post request successfully and create the users***

[image]

- Please check **`POST`** request requirements and permissions needed and make sure they are granted admin consent.It can be permissions with `scopes that are granted to particular web api`.
- Make sure the access token or user interaction is done and permissions required are granted.